# Rmarkdown, printing a dataframe

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to knit a data frame to a pdf output in my r code chunk, but I do not want to see the hashtags on the pdf when the data.frame is printed, how do I suppress the hashtag signs from appearing on my pdf file, my code is

````
```{r table1, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}

tab1 <- data.frame(row.names = c("Number of cases per year", "Number of deaths per year", "Five-year net Survival", "25-year Prevalence"), Male=c(157,87,"54.9%",1025), Female=c(65, 43, "39.7%", 349), Allpersons=c(222,130,"50.0%",1347))

print(tab1, quote = FALSE, row.names = T)
```
````

do anyone has a solution to this, I appreciate the help

best regards
Tewodros

Comment: Use `knitr::kable()` instead of `print()`

Comment: Thank you Phil, I wasted a lot of time on this, `knitr::kable()` works brilliantly :)